# Update WPF datagrid after changes happen in the sqlite database

Tags: c#, database, wpf, orm, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to update my datagrid  after I update/add/delete items from the database. Should I create a thread running in a loop and query the database?

I'm using servicestack.ormlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Look at ObservableCollections, they basically do that you want. Need your model to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Do you think it's a good idea to work with an ObservableCollection in the UI and to subscribe to the "collectionchanged" event. So when the collection changed, I update the items in the database?